# Map one SQL table to two C# entities with one to many relation

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have one SQL table that I need to map to two entities in EF core. The relation should looks like one to many. I need to get a result as if it was normal group by.

[image]

The expected result "like group by Model and Ver" should be like
[image]

The entities code :

```
public class ModelVersionControl
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string UnitId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext :

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<ModelVersionControl> ModelVersions { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Normal dbset has coulmn name configuartions etc ....
        modelBuilder.Entity<ModelVersionControl>()
            .HasMany<Item>(mr => mr.Items)
            .WithOne();
    }
}
```

I can not get this to work :(
Any help ? what I'm missing

**Note :** I don't want to use group by. I need to have entity "ModelVersionControl" with navigation property to "Items" using EF model

Comment: Why?  `GroupBy` is not working?

Comment: I don't want to use group by. I need to have entity "ModelVersionControl" with navigation property to "Items" using EF model

Comment: dbContext cannot take one database table and break into two c# classes.  Models have to map one-to-one.  You can create non dbContext objects and split.  When designing a database you have think how you are going to use the objects.  It may be best to fix the database and create the tables the way you want to use them.

Comment: Actually  I can map the same DB table to different two nested  entities (one with complex sub type) just if the relation is one to one. The problem here is because the relation is one to many. Regarding modify the database, it is not possible as the database already exist and not under my control "Database existed first"